# how to define dynamic variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-3

when i define in javascript

```
var whoami = @ViewBag.myname
```

it is not work or render they render

```
var whoami = ;
```

i am trying it  @(ViewBag.myname) // not worked too.

are their any way to do this in raor MVC 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `@ViewBag.myname` empty?

Enclose the variable in quotes, so to have a correct javascript string:

```
var whoami = "@ViewBag.myname";
```

also ensure that `myname` doesn't contain quotes too (or escape them).

Comment: i am not try it but i solve the problem by another way not using this.